# sqlalchemy create insert object without named keywords

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy

In the documentation the way to create a row to insert is written like this:

```
insert_obj = MyTable(column1="a", column2="b")
```

Now suppose i have the row in a list and i want to create this object without the named keywords? Something like this (that it gets the right column from the position in the list):

```
row = ["a", "b"]
insert_obj = MyTable(row)
```

My usecase:

```
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///database/test.db')
engine.connect()

Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
session = Session(bind=engine)

df = pd.read_csv("../test.csv", sep=';')
Articles = Base.classes.articles
inserts = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    insert.append(Articles(article_id=row[0], article_name=row[1]))
session.add_all(inserts)
session.commit()
```

i want to get rid of the named keywords in the loop.

The solution is to use `Articles.__table__.insert().values(row)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sql_alchemy Documentation:

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Insert.values

> Also for either form but more typically for the Insert construct, a tuple that contains an entry for every column in the table is also accepted:

```
MyTable.__table__.insert().values(("a", "b"))
```

Note, tuple should have an entry for every column. Can you elaborate on your usecase?

Comment: I made an update Articles.insert() throws an error: AttributeError 'articles' object has no attribute  'insert'

Comment: The solution is to use Articles.__table__.insert().values(row).